# Howto prevent nix-build substituting path in source file?

Tags: nix

I'm building a package via nix-build. In the source file *FindPackage.cmake*, a path `/usr/lib/libicucore.dylib` is hardcoded, and nix-build will automatically substitute to `/var/empty/lib/libicucore.dylib` for security. But how can I prevent this substitution? Or tell nix-build to add any path into reserved list?

---

In *FindPackage.cmake*:

```
    # Apple builds have a unique location for ICU
    if (APPLE AND "${package}" STREQUAL "ICU")
        set(_found_package ON)

        set(ICU_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/ICU/Headers)

        # Apple just has a single dylib for ICU
        set(ICU_I18N_LIBRARY /usr/lib/libicucore.dylib)
        set(ICU_UC_LIBRARY /usr/lib/libicucore.dylib)
        set(ICU_DATA_LIBRARY /usr/lib/libicucore.dylib)

        set(ICU_LIBRARIES ${ICU_UC_LIBRARY})
        set(ICU_FOUND ON)
    endif ()
```

Using `nix-build -K` to keep build directory, I found `/usr/lib/libicucore.dylib` was substituted to `/var/empty/lib/libicucore.dylib`.

Comment: What is `FindPackage.cmake`? How is nix substituting the file path in there? Might help to provide a lot more info.

Answer (score 0):

It's substituted by `fixCmakeFiles()` in *nixpkgs/pkgs/development/tools/build-managers/cmake/setup-hook.sh* . Setting `dontFixCmake = true` fixes it.